# calculating optimal chunk size for Linux software-RAID

Tags: software-raid, mdadm

Am I correct that optimal chunk size is average file read/written to disk divided by number of block devices in RAID array storing the data? For example if the average file size is 1024KiB and I have four disks in RAID1, then I should choose the chunk size around 256KiB? Or if I have two drives in RAID0, then I should choose the chunk size 512KiB instead? Or are there better methods/benchmarks to determine the optimal chunk size for software-RAID?
Last but not least, is there a good utility which could help one to measure the average I/O read/write size?

Comment: Take a look at [this wiki page](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#Advanced_Options).  It explains chunk size in pretty good detail.  Also take a look at [this page](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Performance).  It has benchmarks galore including links to benchmarking utilities.